# Iterate n rows for 2 dataframes in Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have a large training and validation dataset.
There are 40,000 rows for training and 40,000 rows for validation. But I don't use the entire dataset at once.
I want to run the regression every 1000 rows of training, do prediction for corresponding
1000 rows of validation, then calculate the error and then proceed to do the same for next 1000 rows of training and validation.
So I repeat this process 40 times. How do I do this in Python?

Any example code will greatly help me as I am very much lost.

I tried zip with iterrows but it isnt working.I know df.iterrows can help me iterate over the rows and zip will help me iterate over corresponding rows of the two dataframes but how  do I do both?

Comment: `df.iloc[start:start+1000]` inside a loop that increments `start` by 1000 each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.split(df, 40)` on each `DataFrame` to split them into 40 parts. Subsequently, you can use a `for loop` in conjunction with `zip()` to perform a parallel iteration over both `lists` of `DataFrames` - see code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example data
factor = 10_000
data = {
    'col_1': [1, 2, 3, 4] * factor,
    'col_2': [100, 200, 300, 400] * factor
}
training_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
validation_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(training_df.shape)  # (40000, 2)
print(validation_df.shape)  # (40000, 2)

# split DataFrame's into 40 parts - this gives you a list of dfs
training_dfs = np.split(training_df, 40)
validation_dfs = np.split(validation_df, 40)
print(training_dfs[0].shape)  # (1000, 2)
print(validation_dfs[-1].shape)  # (1000, 2)

# parallel iteration
for train_df, val_df in zip(training_dfs, validation_dfs):

    # train model on train_df
    # validate model on val_df
    # print metrics
    pass
```